# Getting estimated means (and plotting them) after glmer?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

I'm migrating from STATA to R, and this is one of the last few things that's causing me some trouble. My data is of the following format: each subject takes a five-question test at the beginning of class. Some study, some don't. Finally, all subjects take a final test at the end of class. The three variables are 0/1 (wrong/right) and 0/1 (no study/study). For convenience, he's an example of the dataset:

```
dat <- data.frame(
   id = 1:20,
   first_test = sample(0:1, 100, replace = TRUE),
   final_test = sample(0:1, 100, replace = TRUE),
   study = sample(0:1, 100, replace = TRUE))

dat <- dat[order(dat$id), ]
```

I'm interested in how studying and initial test performance affect final test performance, so I run the following model:

```
glmer(final_test ~ study * first_test + (1|id), family = "binomial", data = dat)
```

What I would like to do is get the estimated means on the final test across all four levels of the interaction. In STATA, this is simple: after fitting the model, I just run the [margins](http://www.stata.com/manuals13/rmargins.pdf) command:

```
margins, over(first_test study)

margins
```

And I get the following [output and graph.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ippnB.jpg)

Is there a way to do the same thing in R? I'm guessing maybe using the *predict()* function? Any help is much appreciated!